# crystal reports default parameter

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I work with Oracle hospitality's Materials Control. this system uses crystal reports 2008 to process its reports. However some reports require me to input a parameter prior to viewing or printing the report. whilst automating these reports I'm currently running unto the issue that I can't preset these parameters and thus can't print automatically.

Since my software support center cant help me and I don't have the crystal reports development software, or access to any other development software other then notepad ++, I was hoping someone here might know of a different way of setting a default parameter for a Crystal Reports file?

Any advice given would be greatly appreciated.

With kind regards,

Wouter

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your crystal report from any server where report is installed then you can pass the parameter same as in URL.
Below is the example we are using to pass the input parameter

```
https://url_link_of_env/openDocument.jsp? 
DocID=crystal_report_name_or_id&sIDType=CUID&sType=rpt&sRefresh=Y

Here sIDType, sType and sRefresh are input parameters.
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately there is only a stand alone viewer present, no report server has been installed. the information for the reports are passed inside .ttx, .qrp and .ini files.